# Regex using the ? Operator in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a sample string that I want to match: `"a123456.java,a12344*javaaaaaaaaaaaaa"`

I use the following regex pattern: `Pattern p=Pattern.compile("a[0-9]+[.]?[a-zA-Z]+");`

Now the ? operator means 0 or more occurrences of `"."`. Why is the string `"a12344*javaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` not picked up by this? Why is the `*` character not counted as a 0 occurrence?

Comment: `?` operator mean 0 or 1. 0 or more is `*` operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean that you expected the * to be picked up by the `.` because that means 'anything':

Inside the character class, the `.` becomes a literal `.`, instead of the character meaning 'anything'.

If you want to match anything, then use `.?` instead of `[.]?`

---

If you meant that `*` is not `.`, so is zero occurrences of `.`:

You are right, but in your regex, the `.` must be followed by a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`), and the `*` is obviously not a letter.

To clarify, you have:

```
a -> "a"
[0-9]+ -> "12344"
[.]? -> ""
[a-zA-Z]+ -> Cannot match "*"
```

Comment: So what is the difference between saying [a]? and saying a?     ??

Comment: There is none, but there is a difference between `[.]` and `.`. In the first case, it means 'a period'. In the second case, it means 'any character (except a newline)'.

Answer (score 0):

right regex: `a[0-9]+.*[a-zA-Z]+`

`[.]` mean symbol `.`

`?` mean 0 or 1

Comment: thanks got it. I did not know that . and [.] are different. Thanks everyone for their time.